# How can I record a phone conversation on my PC, with permission?

Tags: modem, audio-recording

How to do this?

I would like to record voice. We keep a mic in the pink port.

What do I need to set to record from the telephone cable attached to the modem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [software](http://www.telephone-recording.com/) solutions that just use your sound card, or there are [hardware](http://www.digital-loggers.com/T1.html?gclid=CP2Br63JzaQCFQoBbAodrWa5Ew) solutions that are USB or PCI that are better, but much more expensive.

Comment: Please can you elaborate with more then just links. If those links stop working this answer will have no value to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do if you make/receive a phone call from Skype, directly from your PC.

There is also an app for Windows Mobile 6 that lets you record all phone calls (I used it and it worked really well).

Answer (score 0):

[Google Voice](http://voice.google.com/) allows you to record phone calls (notifying the other end) you receive through it. Domestic calls (US, Canada) in and out are free currently, though that may change in the near future.

Comment: Google Voice currently allows only incoming calls to be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to use Google Voice which allows you to forward incoming calls on your personal Google Voice number to any existing number and provides advanced features such as recording calls.

Along the same line are Voice over IP Providers (e.g. [SipGate](http://www.sipgate.com/)) which also provide a phone number and allow you to record calls.

Either solution would allow you to either download or receive the recordings by email.

Comment: Google voice currently allows only incoming calls to be recorded.